# How to save to a file system directory in Grails

Tags: grails, file-upload

I am trying to save an uploaded file into the file system directory, and allow other users to download it.

I am currently saving it in my database and not in my file system directory. Here is my code:

```
class Document {
    String filename
    byte[] filedata           
    Date uploadDate = new Date()

    static constraints = {
        filename(blank: false, nullable:false)
        filedata(blank: true, nullable: true, maxSize:1073741824)
    }
}
```

and my controller for uploading the file is:

```
class DocumentController {

    static allowedMethods = [delete: "POST"]

    def index = {
        redirect(action: "list", params: params)
    }

    def list() {
        params.max = 10
        [documentInstanceList: Document.list(params), documentInstanceTotal: Document.count()]
    }

    def uploadPage() {

    }

    def upload() {
        def file = request.getFile('file')
        if(file.isEmpty())
        {
            flash.message = "File cannot be empty"
        }
        else
        {
            def documentInstance = new Document()
            documentInstance.filename = file.getOriginalFilename()
            documentInstance.filedata = file.getBytes()
            documentInstance.save()    
        }
        redirect (action: 'list')
    }
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21519144/how-to-upload-file-into-server-directory-with-grails

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you could do a fuction similar to the one below:

```
boolean upload(MultipartFile uploadFile, String fileUploadDir){
    String uploadDir = !fileUploadDir.equals('') ?: 'C:/temp' //You define the path where the file will be saved
    File newFile = new File("$uploadDir/${uploadFile.originalFilename}"); //You create the destination file
    uploadFile.transferTo(newFile); //Transfer the data

    /**You would need to create an independent Domain where to store the path of the file or have the path directly in your domain*/

}
```

Since you will only need to save the path of the file you could add a string to your domain to store it or you could create an independent domain to store the data of your file. You will also need to add try/catch statements where needed.

And to retrieve the file you would need to add to your controller something like the next code:

```
File  downloadFile = new File(yourFileDomain?.pathProperty) //get the file using the data you saved in your domain
if(downloadFile){ //Set your response properties
            response.characterEncoding = "UTF-8"
            response.setHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"${yourFileDomain?.fileNameProperty}\"" //add the header with the filename you saved in your domain you could also set a default filename
            //response.setHeader "Content-disposition", "attachment; filename=\"myfile.txt\""
            response.outputStream << new FileInputStream(downloadFile) 
            response.outputStream.flush()
            return
        }
```

Hope this helps, any comments are welcome.

Comment: Are you generating the original file name on server side to avoid filesystem naming conflicts?

Comment: @Alexjjsmith, In my actual controller I save the file using a random UUI and the original file extension, thus avoiding filename conflicts in the server where I store the files. It also lets me put all of the files in a single, or limited amount of folders to help me move the files, if necessary. Sometimes I also store the original filename to return the file with it´s original filename to the user.